# PHP not executing using phoneGap in Xcode simulator - using AJAX, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xcode, cordova

I am creating an application in an HTML5/Javascript/CSS3 implementation.
I have an external PHP file on my localhost and am trying to communicate with it using jQuery and AJAX. Everything works fine if I load the file in my browser, and I get the desired response from the PHP file. However when running it in Xcode's simulator, I just receive the whole PHP script as the response. I don't know why it isn't executing.

HTML form:

```
<form id="loginForm" method = "post" action="PHP/login.php">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" style="width: 200px;"><br>
<input type="password" name ="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 200px;"><br>
<button type="submit" id="login" style="float: right;">Login</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $("button#login").click(function (){
      u = $("#username").val();
      p = $("#password").val();
      if($("#username").val()==""||$("#password").val()=="")
          alert("Please enter username and password");
          else
          $.post( $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
          function(data){
                alert(data);
                });
          $("#loginForm").submit( function(){
                return false;
                });
          });
});
```

PHP connecting to MYSQL database:

```
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "************")
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("VLA",$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select examples");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE (username='$username' AND password = '$pass')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row[0] > 0){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
    }
```

Would appreciate any sort of help!

Comment: Sounds to me like you are including the .php file in the iOS project. That will not work, it should be hosted on a server. If you are aware of that and try to have the simulator communicate with a .php file hosted on your Mac, you should probably prefix the php url with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks. I had tried referencing the php file on the server as well as putting the project folder itself on the server too but keep getting the same problem. The code works perfectly on a browser but on the simulator I just get the php script returned to me. what do you mean by the prefix? do you mean 127.0.0.1/PHP/login.php?

Answer (score 0):

Modified your php file, convert result data in json data.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $("button#login").click(function (){
      u = $("#username").val();
      p = $("#password").val();
      if($("#username").val()==""||$("#password").val()==""){
            alert("Please enter username and password");
      }else{   
            var ajax_call = your_servicepath+'PHP/login.php';                 
            var form = $('#loginForm').serialize();                    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax_call,
                data: form,
                dataType: "json",
                success:  function(response){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            });
      }
   });
});
```